# Passing an Object as a function parameter in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular component that contains a function. In this function, I need to pass an Object as a function parameter and call this function with the function parameters. It´s been a while since I have been working with Angular and at the type, "any" was the return type to use with functions; nowadays it seems to be "undefined". However, I am not sure on how to write the function call with the corresponding parameters and would appreciate any help and hints. Thanks in advance!

Here´s the component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', //  eslint-disable-line @angular-eslint/component-selector
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public interactionID: number=0;
  @Input()
  public userdata!: Object;


  constructor() {
    // Called first time before the ngOnInit()

  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

  this.NewWorkItem(this.interactionID, this.userdata );
    
  }

  public NewWorkItem(interactionID: unknown, userData: { FirstName: unknown; LastName: unknown }): void  {
    console.log('NewWorkItem call',interactionID,userData);

    const event: Event = new CustomEvent ('wde.newWorkItem', {
      detail: {
        FirstName: userData.FirstName,
        LastName: userData.LastName,
        InteractionID: interactionID
      },
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      composed: false,
    });
    console.log('NewWorkItem event',event);  
    window.dispatchEvent(event);

  }
}
```

This is the function that needs to be called in ngOnInit:

```
public NewWorkItem(interactionID: unknown, userData: { FirstName: unknown; LastName: unknown }): void  {
    console.log('NewWorkItem call',interactionID,userData);

    const event: Event = new CustomEvent ('wde.newWorkItem', {
      detail: {
        FirstName: userData.FirstName,
        LastName: userData.LastName,
        InteractionID: interactionID
      },
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      composed: false,
    });
    console.log('NewWorkItem event',event);  
    window.dispatchEvent(event);

  }
```

This is the function call in ngOnInit, where I am having the troubles in passing the paramters correctly:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {

  this.NewWorkItem(this.interactionID, this.userdata );
    

  }
```

this.userdata cannot be passed as such as function parameter; the compiler error is:

```
The argument of Typ "Object" cannot be assigned to the parameter of type "{ FirstName: unknown; LastName: unknown; }"
```

I was trying to call the function in the ngOnInit method with the corresponding parameters.
The error that I get is: The argument of Typ "Object" cannot be assigned to the parameter of type `"{ FirstName: unknown; LastName: unknown; }"`. I cannot tell on how to pass the object as a function parameter correctly.

Comment: You will have to ensure that `this.userdata` is of the correct type. Your problem is here `public userdata!: Object;` there is basically ***never*** a good time to use the `Object` type, and certainly not here where you already know the shape of the object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export as a separated interface:

```
export interface IUserData { FirstName: unknown; LastName: unknown }
```

And then:

```
@Input() public userdata!: IUserData;
...
public NewWorkItem(interactionID: unknown, userData: IUserData);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a type for userData:

```
type UserData = { FirstName: string; LastName: string };
```

Then you should use the `UserData` type to type the userData property and parameter.

property:

```
@Input() public userdata!: UserData;
```

parameter:

```
public NewWorkItem(interactionID: unknown, userData: UserData): void  {
```